# Microsoft bot framework: What must a messaging endpoint return?

Tags: rest, botframework

I am implementing my own messaging endpoint for a MS Teams bot from scratch. I'm almost there. The endpoint does get called with conversationUpdate events, but I see:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
> BadRequest

in the admin on https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=...

I am probably returning something bad in the HTTP request. As I didn't find anything about the response in the REST API docs, I am just sending the string "{}" with a standard content type.

So what do I actually need to return?

Edit: It appears that the relevant part of the botbuilder-java package is this function in ControllerBase.java:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Activity activity = getActivity(request);
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        adapter.processIncomingActivity(
            authHeader, activity, turnContext -> bot.onTurn(turnContext)
        ).handle((result, exception) -> {
            if (exception == null) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
                return null;
            }

            if (exception.getCause() instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            } else {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }

            return null;
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this only sets a return code (202) but does not return any content. I now try to do the same thing in my messaging endpoint, but Teams still complains about "BadRequest".

Edit: I have snooped what the actual BotFramework Java sample does - it just returns a code 202 with an empty request body and no content type. I'm now doing the exact same thing, and Teams still complains that it could not send the message. Kinda giving up here.

Comment: are you following any specific botbuilder sample?

Comment: @ranusharao I ran this one: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/tree/main/samples/02.echo-bot